# Does a backbone view linger on after deletion of the corresponding DOM node?

Tags: backbone.js, garbage-collection

We have some legacy non-backbone code in our web application. Although we attach `views` to existing DOM elements there is still some *yet-to-be-refactored* code that deletes certain DOM elements i.e. the delete call doesn't go through the view but is more like a jQuery call `$('#domID').remove();`

I have a nagging feeling that the backbone view probably hangs around as a zombie, but I don't have a way to see it? Is this harmful? Should we make it priority to refactor and have all the deletes go via the view and call `view.remove()` and `view.unbind()` for proper deletion?

Would the view be garbage collected if the DOM node is deleted independently? I guess if not if it's bound to some event, but what if it isn't?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The view will only linger on if there is a reference to it somewhere. There are four sources of stray references to consider:

1. Bindings to models and collections, i.e. `this.collection.on('reset', this.render)` and such.
2. Bindings to DOM objects through the view's `events`.
3. Bindings to DOM objects through direct `$(...).on(...)` calls.
4. Plain old variable references such as `this.current_view = new V(...)`.

**(1)** is normally handled by the view's [`remove`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove) method and you have to call `remove` yourself, there's nothing in Backbone or jQuery that can do this for you. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/e574Z/

**(2)** is easy. Backbone views use a single [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) call to bind the view's events to the view's `el`. So, if you remove the view's `el` through a simple `$(x).remove()` then the event reference goes away. However, if you're attaching different views to the same `el`, you'll need to call [`undelegateEvents`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-undelegateEvents) to detach the `delegate`; this would normally be done in a `remove` method:

```
remove: function() {
    this.undelegateEvents();
    return this;
}
```

but, again, you have to call `remove` yourself somewhere.

**(3)** is rare but sometimes necessary in the case of window scroll events, body click events for dialogs, and things like that. Of course, you have to clean these up yourself as Backbone can't know what you're doing behind its back and the elements that you're binding to would be outside of the view's `el` (or you'd be in **(2)**). Where would you clean these up? The `remove` method of course.

**(4)** is, as always, up to you. Usually, this sort of thing is handled like this:

```
if(this.current_view)
    this.current_view.remove();
this.current_view = null;
```

Yes, there's `remove` again.

---

So, if all you have are things like **(2)**, then `$('#domID').remove();` will be fine and shouldn't leave any zombies; in fact, the default [`remove`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove) implementation is just `this.$el.remove()` and the documentation says as much:

> **remove** `view.remove()`
>
> Convenience function for removing the view from the DOM. Equivalent to calling `$(view.el).remove();`

However, you probably have some things like **(1)** involved as well so adding/updating all your `remove` methods and calling `view.remove()` to remove views would be a good idea.